# Right zero in a finite semigroup

Tags: group-theory, semigroups, finite-semigroups

Let $(M, \cdot)$ be a finite semigroup such that

$$ x,y\in M\wedge \exists a,b\in M:x=a⋅y\wedge y=b⋅x\Rightarrow x=y. $$

Show that M contains at least one right absorbant element(or right zero).

Using that there exists an $x^n=x$ for $x\in M$ because it is a finite semigroup I got that $(M, \cdot)$ is a idempotent semigroup but I'm not sure it's correct.I don't know how to continue.

Comment: What about a group where $a=b=e$? That doesn't have a zero element. That seems to satisfy your condition

Comment: @MattSamuel Maybe OP's condition misses somethin like $a\neq b$. I don't know.

Comment: What do you mean by "Using that there exists an $x^n=x$ for $x\in M$ because it is a finite semigroup"?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition means that $M$ is $\mathcal{L}$-trivial, i.e. the [Green's relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) $\mathcal{L}$ is the equality. Since $M$ is finite, it has a [minimum ideal](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Minimal_ideal) $I$, which is a completely simple semigroup. Moreover, since $M$ is $\mathcal{L}$-trivial, $I$ is actually a [right zero band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_(mathematics)#Zero_bands), and all its elements are right zeroes.